# Bootstrap text element with line behind text

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm looking to create text headers that have a line behind the text to fill the entire width of the container, like this example:

Example:

[image]

The actual text itself would have a white box around it as to block out the line.

```
.divider-text {
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
```

This code here fills the entire text container with the `#e5e5e5` color.

Comment: A simple Google-ing for "css text with line behind" gives http://codepen.io/ericrasch/pen/Irlpm.

Comment: try this http://plnkr.co/edit/JgS6EwOUTaiV9UfyOXr1?p=preview

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider the following markup and CSS

```css
.heading-1{
  position:relative;
  text-align: center
}
.heading-1:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-top: solid 2px #bebebe;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 0;
}
.heading-1 span {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="heading-1"><span>Centered Text</span></h1>
```

Comment: superb, this way if text is too wide on small screen won't overlap with background. So this solution is good for responsive too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a simple way, using two options.

**Background Image**

The first one involves a background image to be there:

```css
h1 {text-align: center; background-color: #fff; background: url("http://i.imgur.com/Kkw7rPC.png?1") center center repeat-x #fff;}
h1 .text {background-color: #fff; padding: 10px; display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<h1><span class="text">Hello</span></h1>
```

**Border and Overflowing Content**

This is like you have a border and the content will overflow out making the CSS more complex:

```css
h1 {text-align: center; position: relative; background-color: #fff;}
h1 .border {border-bottom: 3px solid #999; position: absolute; width: 100%; left: 0; top: 50%; margin-top: -1px; z-index: 1;}
h1 .text {background-color: #fff; position: relative; z-index: 2; padding: 10px; display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<h1><span class="border"></span><span class="text">Hello</span></h1>
```